# Ways to express "something bad is going to happen"

Tags: phrase-requests

How can I express *something bad is going to happen* in a better way. Something along the lines of *An ominous chain of events is starting to ensue*

Comment: Can you give an example? What kind of word do you want? Noun? (premonition) Verb? (foreshadow) Adjective? (foreboding)

Comment: (I just want to clarify that the above comment isn't providing answers, only examples. I think out of all of them, only "premonition" the dark connotation you're looking for)

Comment: Taking premonition as an example, what's the right way to use this word in a sentence that conveys the same meaning as 'something bad is going to happen'

Comment: "Walking along the road, Fred suddenly had a premonition of great calamity".

Comment: Or something like 'The terrible flash of lightning indicates... "

Comment: *There's a storm coming, IPing7*.

Comment: Please consolidate the further hints from your comments into the question. Otherwise it will be surely closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for *informal asides*:

- "I have a bad feeling about this..."
- "Nothing good can come of this."
- "The s**t's about to hit the fan." (colloquial, and offensive to some)
- "You think this is bad, wait 'til you see what's about to happen." (when the situation is already discernably "bad")
- "Well, that's thrown a spanner in the works." (BritE, and said after observing the precipitating event)
- "Uh-oh."

If you're asking about how to notify a superior of an impending system failure or political snafu, you could try:

- "(Sir/Mr...insert title here), there's no good way to say this, but... [brief statement of the impending consequences of the failure]. But I think I have a way to (avert/mitigate/contain the damage)/(correct the problem)." (Explanation of what happened to follow upon request.) Do your best to bring at least one proposed solution when reporting the problem, and ideally bring a small party of experts with you.

I had to read quite a bit into your question; I trust some of this will be helpful.

Comment: I like the third one best.

Comment: I wanted an expression for writing and not for speaking, but these points are certainly going to come in handy in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: @MickSharpe I eliminate any scatological reference by changing that to, "The hype has hit the fan".

Comment: @PeterPoint Your intentions are noble. In my answer, I was aiming for journalistic accuracy, and it seems I hit it.

Answer (score 1):

> "something bad is going to happen"

=

> There was a sense of foreboding.

**Edit:**

For example, before he was assassinated, Martin Luther King, Jr., *felt a sense of foreboding.*

Comment: @aperente001 I believe your suggestion would work well in a literary function, such as a novel. I believe the OP is looking for how to convey a message to someone else, rather than a mood to an audience/a reader.

Comment: @jaxter - How did you get this?  "I wanted an expression for writing and not for speaking."

Answer (score 0):

**Portentous**: Portentous events, statements, or signs...[that] show that something unpleasant is very likely to happen. (Cambridge Dictionary)

(Word/sentence-in-context) The report contains numerous **portentous** references to a future environmental catastrophe. (Cambridge Dictionary)